# How can I specify n_fft in Librosa pitch shifting effects

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, librosa, pitch-shifting

I am using the [librosa pitch shift](https://librosa.org/doc/0.7.0/generated/librosa.effects.pitch_shift.html) method on an ecg.

```
pitch_shifting = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(ecg, 500, n_steps=100)
```

The ECG is segmented at 512 values per segment, thus window is 512. Librosa defaults to `n_fft=2048`. How can change this? the function doesn't accept `n_fft` as a parameter. Checking the docs and source code, it says find the `**kwargs` at `librosa.decompose.stft` which doesn't exist or couldn't find.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried specifying n_fft? If so, what is the error that you get?

Comment: Btw, you probably should specify hop_length as well